# Ansible wait_for not response correct error

Tags: testing, ansible, connectivity

I trying to test a batch of connection but the connections that fail all error resposnses are "Timeout" but I know (I tested) some of them are "no route to host".
How I can do that with wait_for in ansible?

```
- name: Test connectivity flow
  wait_for: 
    host: "{{ item.destination_ip }}"
    port: "{{ item.destination_port }}"
    state: started         # Port should be open
    delay: 0               # No wait before first check (sec)
    timeout: 3             # Stop checking after timeout (sec)
  delegate_to: "{{ item.source_ip }}"
  failed_when: false
  register: test_connectivity_flow_result

- name: Append result message to result list msg
  set_fact:
    result_list_msg: "{% if test_connectivity_flow_result.msg is defined %}{{ result_list_msg + [test_connectivity_flow_result.msg] }}{% else %}{{ result_list_msg + [ '' ] }}{% endif %}"
```

Current response: Timeout when waiting for 1.1.1.1:1040

Expected response: No route to host 1.1.1.1:1040

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the title of the documentation of the [`wait_for` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html)

> wait_for – Waits for a condition before continuing

If I "rephrase" the condition your have written, this would give something like: "wait for host X to be a resolvable destination and for port 22 to be opened on that destination, retry with no delay and timeout after 3s".

This could typically be a test you launch because you started a new vm and registered it in a dns. So you wait for the dns to propagate AND the ssh port being available.

In your case, you get a timeout because your hostname never becomes a resolvable address.

If you specifically want to test there is no route to host and don't want to wait until the route eventually becomes available, you need to do that an other way. Here is a simple example playbook with the `ping` module:

```
---
- name: Very basic connection test 
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Test if host is reachable (will report no route if so)
      ping:
      delegate_to: nonexistent.host.local
```

Which results in:

```
PLAY [Very basic connection test] *****************************************************

TASK [Test if host is reachable (will report no route if so)] *************************
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname nonexistent.host.local: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Note that the [`ping` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html):

- Will report that there is no route to host if so
- Will implicitly try to connect to port 22
- Will make sure that the host has python installed and is ready to be managed through ansible.

If the host you are trying to check should not meet all of the above conditions (e.g. you want the test to succeed even if python is not installed), you will need an other scenario. Running the ICMP `ping` through the `command` module is one of the multiple solutions.

Comment: But I want to test different ports some of them will be timeout othens will be no route to host.

Comment: Then first test the route, then test the ports on the hosts where you have a route.

Comment: How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like that:

```
       - name: Check if port {{ R_PORT }} is open. If it is, let's fail and investigate manually.
         shell: ss -ltpn | grep :{{ R_PORT }} | wc -l
         register: open_redis_port

       - debug: msg="{{ open_redis_port.stdout }}"

       - name: Fail playbook execution if port {{ R_PORT }} is open
         fail:
           msg: Port {{ R_PORT }} is open. Failing, please investigate manually.
         when: open_redis_port.stdout == "2" or open_redis_port.stdout == "1"
```